# Translation of Hosutofamiri- no Minasan (ホストファミリーのみなさん)

Tags: translation, particle-の

It's either:

- Host family of everyone's
- Host family of your's (I got this from Google Translator)

This is from Mirai Book 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Minasan* (皆【みな】さん） means *everyone*, and it's mainly used as a vocative, just like you say in English, "Hello, *everyone*!" to people in front of you.

*Hosutofamiri- no* （ホストファミリーの） modifies *Minasan*. And in this case, the particle *no* （の） indicates the host family is in [apposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) to *Minasan*. (Ex. Rudolph, the reindeer = トナカイ**の**ルドルフ; My friend Kevin = 友達**の**ケビン)

So ホストファミリーの皆さん refers to *everyone* in front of the speaker, who are host families of someone. It can be *my* host family, or *yours*, or *theirs*, depending on the context. The literal translation would be "everyone in (somobody's) host family".

Comment: Yeah, in this context, it's "My Host Family", since the person writing it is talking about his host family. (Thank you.)

Comment: @VanTran more specifically this means "everyone in the host family"... not necessarily "my host family" (though context might infer that it is everyone in my host family.

Comment: @virmaior Oh, so it's referring to "everyone in my/their/anyone's host family". Okay, thanks for clearing that up.